# "operation is not allowed when the object is closed" - when trying to read and fetch the data from excel sheet via ADODB connection in hp-uft

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

[Operation is not allowed_error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ga8TI.png)Hi All,

I am getting below error while trying to execute the script. This is coming while trying to open and read the excel via ADODB connection.The error is due to **"Operation is not allowed when the object is closed**.", "Unexpected error from external database driver (1)."

Error message - "operation is not allowed when the object is closed"

Code:

```
Public Function GetData(strDatabaseType, strfileName_SQL, strSheetNameDBName,intMode)
    On Error Resume Next

    Const adOpenStatic = 3
    Const adLockOptimistic = 3

    Set objConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set objGetData = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    Set objCom = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    Select Case strDatabaseType

    Case "Excel"
                If intMode = 0 Then
                    objConn.Open "Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};DriverId=790;Dbq=" & strfileName_SQL & ";DefaultDir=C:\;"
                    objGetData.Open "Select * from [" & strSheetNameDBName & "$]", objConn
                    Set GetData = objGetData
                ElseIf intMode = 1 Then
                    objConn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & strfileName_SQL & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;"";"
                    objGetData.Open "Select * from [" & strSheetNameDBName & "$]", objConn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
                    Set GetData = objGetData
                End If

End function
```

From the above code of lines, When the intMode becomes 1, error throwing up at the line -objconn.open

Comment: Step 1 is always: Remove the `On Error Resume Next` as it will mask your problem. You'll probably find an error on the `objGetData.Open` line which will be why you are failing to open it and therefore get the 'object is closed' error

Comment: No. This is not helping out. I am still getting the errors:

Comment: So it has helped as the error has moved from your get data step to the open connection step, as I suggested it would... The error will be that the connection string is incorrect.

Comment: I have error at this line : objConn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & strfileName_SQL & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;"";"   and  i have modified 'Provider' string to this :    objConn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strfileName_SQL & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;"";"      ... After this change also i having the same error.

Comment: Is `strFileName_Sql` set properly?

Comment: Yes..  I have checked it..  That's fine..

Comment: What is the value of `strfileName_SQL`?

Comment: if you are passing relative path in `strfileName_SQL` then too it gives error - check if the path of the data source and path in `strfileName_SQL` is correct